# Can one move controls around in a form class derived from another form?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I have created a forms which are derived from another form thus:-

```
Public Class MyForm
    ' ...etc
End Class

Public Class MyDerivedForm
    Inherits MyBaseForm
    ' ...etc
End Class

Public Class MyOtherDerivedForm
    Inherits MyBaseForm
    ' ...etc
End Class
```

This works quite nicely and I can add controls to the derived form using the form designer. But I'd like to move some of the inherited controls around a bit on `MyDerivedForm` without disturbing `MyBaseForm` or `MyOtherDerivedForm`. I can't see any way of doing this on the forms designer.

Is it possible to do this (preferably with the designer but with code if necessary)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a typical VB.NET problem so not so sure what's going on here.  You'll get the lock icon on the inherited controls and a grayed-out Properties window for an inherited control when the Modifiers property of the control in the base class is Private.  The Winforms designer observes the accessibility of the base class member.  Private members can't be messed with.  The default value for Modifiers is Friend in VB.NET, Private in C#.

Make it Friend to allow the derived form class to modify the control properties.  If the base form class lives in another assembly then Friend isn't good enough, you'll need Public.

The Anchor property *can* be an issue, but only if you anchor to the right or bottom.  The control has a knack for ending up in the wrong spot when the derived form has a different size from the base form if the control is anchored that way.  Simply avoided by not anchoring at the right/bottom in the base class and changing the anchor in the derived class.

Comment: For some reason, I have a base Form with Public modifier set on all controls (C# in VS2013).  In the subclass, when I load the form in the designer, my controls properties are greyed out in the Property window.  I have never seen it behave this way - might just be me.  Its driving me nuts, I might start a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

In my VB.NET WinForms application I have inherited forms and I can just grab the inherited controls in the designer and move them about as I would with non-inherited controls on the form.

However I have noticed two things in the past that stop this. If you change the position of the controls on the base form, or change some of the positioning properties (such as anchor or docking), then this can (but not always) move your inherited controls. Also I couldn't move some of my inherited controls in an earlier version of .NET (2.0 I believe), but I never figured out the cause for that so I had to resort to changing the locations via the property grid.

Comment: Now you come to mention it, the immobile controls are indeed anchored to the (lower right) corner of the form; a desirable thing, in this case. It's just that I'd like them sometimes to be anchored in a slightly different place. The property grid for these controls is entirely disabled.

Comment: Sigh. Removing the anchoring in the base class didn't allow the controls to be moved around in the derived class. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: What kind controls are you trying to move? I know some more complex controls (those with internal collections like DataGridView which have rows) and some third party controls just simply don't support the visual inheritance in the designer.

Comment: I'm trying to move buttons.

Comment: I assume you mean the regular .NET buttons, in which case I can't see why they would be causing issues as they are very basic controls.

Comment: @XN15, it seems that the buttons being `Friend` was the problem. As deduced by Hans Passant.

Comment: I was going to suggest that, but I have some controls on my base form that are friend AND movable in the derived forms! All I know for sure is that Visual inheritance is flaky at best! Glad it's sorted.